# Angular2 Get reference to element created in ngFor

Tags: angular

How would I go for referencing an Element in the dom which was created in a ngFor loop.

e.g. I have a list of elements which I iterate over:

```
var cookies: Cookie[] = [...];

<div *ngFor="#cookie of cookies" id="cookie-tab-button-{{cookie.id}}" (click)="showcookie(cookie);">Cookie tab</div>


<div *ngFor="#cookie of cookies" id="cookie-tab-content-{{cookie.id}}" ">Cookie Details</div>
```

How would I reference these divs, so I could add a css class like "is-active".
Or is my approach just wrong.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to add/remove a class use binding

```ts
<div *ngFor="let cookie of cookies" [class.isActive]="someExpression" ....>
```

or

```ts
<div *ngFor="let cookie of cookies" [ngStyle]="{'isActive': someExpression}" ....>
```

Concrete example:

```ts
activeCookie:string = 'b';
cookies:string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

```ts
<div *ngFor="letcookie of cookies" [class.isActive]="cookie == activeCookie" ....>
```

If you really want to get a reference you can use

```ts
<div #someName *ngFor="let cookie of cookies" id="cookie-tab-button-{{cookie.id}}" (click)="showcookie(cookie);">Cookie tab</div>

@ViewChildren('someName') someDivs;

ngAfterViewInit() { // or some event handler
  someDivs.toArray()[0].nativeElement.classList.add('isActive');
}
```

Comment: The expressions are easier in this case I could do class.isActive = cookie.id = selectedCookieId and put it in the component. Thanks that's the easiest.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: hey, I want to get a reference from ngFor, I copied the above code except add "this" in function ngAfterViewInit():  "this.someDivs[0].nativeElement.classList.add('isActive');". However, I got an error: `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`. If I `console.log(this.someDivs); `, it output `QueryList` in the console; If `console.log(this.someDivs);`, its type is object. If `console.log(this.someDivs[0])`, its output is undefined.

Comment: If you add a template variable you can use `@ViewChildren` to query.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks. If I apply *ngFor on <child> (a child component selector) inside of <div>, and there is a public function playVideo() inside child component. I hope to call all of child's playVideo() from parent component to play all the video simultaneously. Right now, I have code `@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;`      `this.child.playVideo();` But in this way, I can only get one child component reference and let one video play. Can you help me?

Comment: Use `@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children : QueryList<ChildComponent>;` ... this.children.toArray()[3].playVideo();`

Answer (score 9):

```
<style>
      .active{
          background:blue;
      }
</style>



<div [ngClass]="{active:(i==selectedIndex)}" 
     *ngFor="#cookie of cookies;#i=index"        
      id="cookie-tab-button-{{cookie.id}}"  
      (click)="showcookie(cookie,i);">Cookie tab
</div>



showcookie(val, i){
        console.log(val + i);
        this.selectedIndex=i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ng-container which not be rendered:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let cookie of cookies">
  <div id="cookie-tab-button-{{cookie.id}}" (click)="showcookie(cookie);">Cookie tab</div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemClick($event.currentTarget)"></div>

itemClick(dom){
  dom.style.color='red';
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation:

In the parent control:

```
// typescript
childControls: ChildComponent[] = [];

<!-- HTML -->
<ng-container *ngFor='let period of periods'>
  <app-child [period]='period' [parent]='this'></app-child>
</ng-container>
```

In the child control:

```
private _parent: ParentComponent;
@Input() set parent(value: ParentComponent) {
  this._parent.childControls.push(this);
}
get parent(): ParentComponent {
  return this._parent;
}
```

This provides an array of references to the child controls in the parent.