# How to show clicked element in *ngFor list hiding others using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want the clicked element in ngFof to display info hidden by ngIf.
Right now clicking on an image all hidden elements are displayed.
How to show the info of the single clicked image?

I do not use jquery in my example because I could not get it to work. 
I am looking to find out how to do it in angular2 before accepting other solutions.
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sa6zXzFtqL6beIEbJC52?p=preview)

```ts
 @Component({

  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: 'src/hello_world.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]

})
export class HelloWorld {

    clicked() {// only show clicked img info 
      e=event.target;
      console.log(e);
      this.show=!this.show;
  };

  info = [{
    data: "information for img1:",
    data2: "only the info img1 is displayed"
  },
    {
      data: "information for img2:",
      data2: "only the info for img2 is displayed"
    },
    {
      data: "information for img3:",
      data2: "only the  info for img3 is displayed"
    }]
}
```

```html
<div  *ngFor="#x of info">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"  (click)="clicked($event)" >


  <div *ngIf="show">
      <div class="names">
        <div class="fullName">{{x.data}}</div>
        <div>{{x.data2}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found this post that has a similar problem albeit I could not implement it in my code.
[angular2-get-reference-to-element-created-in-ngfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147809/angular2-get-reference-to-element-created-in-ngfor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each row data, should use a var `show`:
Here is my code:

```
    export class HelloWorld {
      public show:boolean = false;
      clicked(index) {// only show clicked img info 
        console.log(this.things[index]);
        this.things[index].show = !this.things[index].show;
      };

    public things:Array<any> = [{
    data: "information for img1:",
    data2: "only the info img1 is displayed",
    show: false
  },
    {
      data: "information for img2:",
      data2: "only the info for img2 is displayed"
    },
    {
      data: "information for img3:",
      data2: "only the  info for img3 is displayed"
    }]


}
```

and in html

```
<h3>How to show info of clicked image only </h3>

<div  *ngFor="#x of things;#i = index">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="loading" (click)="clicked(i)" >


  <div *ngIf="x.show">
      <div class="names">
        <div class="fullName">{{x.data}}</div>
        <div>{{x.data2}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/SR2Iguzrgd6DpquCZygc?p=preview

Comment: If the "things" data is coming from an outside resource, how would it be possible to accomplish this without adding the "show:false " property to the "things" array? @dieuhd you have a good solution but the opened info does not close when selecting others.

Comment: @JS_astronauts: You dont need declera `show` in `things`.

Comment: good enough then, now  how to leave only the clicked info open and close previous clicked. If anyone wants has an idea.

Comment: @JS_astronauts: You can use `prevClicked` to save previous `index` clicked. When click to image, you set value `show` of previous clicked images to `false`. I had updated my  plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/SR2Iguzrgd6DpquCZygc?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Just though I would add my 2 cents on this question, mainly because if you are getting data from an `api` you will not be able to manipulate the data to have a boolean property without first pushing onto the array as well as wanting an easier toggle on elements.

The `*ngFor` can hold the index with a simple `*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"`. So we can easily find which index we are handling when we initially hit the `(click)` action and pass in that index to the method `(click)="action(i)"`.

The method can then assign a variable which can be used in a conditional in the `*ngIf` in the element you want to show and hide.

```
action(index){
   this.showElement = index; // assign variable to a number to be used in 
                             // a conditional on the *ngIf
}
```

We now have a variable equal to the clicked index and can therefore create a conditional based on the variable and the index looping in the `*ngFor`. So in the `html` we can add

```
<div *ngIf="showElement === i"> Toggled visibility element </div>
```

So in the case posted by the OP

`component`

```
export class HelloWorld {
   public show:number;

   constructor(){}

   clicked(index){
      this.show = index;
   };
}
```

`html`

```
<div *ngFor="let x of things; let i = index">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150" alt="loading" (click)="clicked(i)" >  

   <div *ngIf="show === i">
       <div class="names">
       <div class="fullName">{{x.data}}</div>
       <div>{{x.data2}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if there is maybe a better way, just dont think that manipulating the data is the best approach to solve view functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a track of selected / clicked id as a seperate component

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let x of things; let i = index;" (click)="toggleOptionsMenu(x.id)" [class.show-more]="x.id === selectedId">{{x}}</li>
</ul> 

selectedId = null;
toggleOptionsMenu(id) {
  this.selectedId = id;
}
```