# Angular: Scroll dynamic element into view knowing only its ID

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dynamic list that gets its data asynchronously, and would like to scroll an specific element into view when the list is loaded.

The list is build similar to this:

```
<div class="items" *ngFor="let item of functionThatGetsItems(); let i = index" [id]="'MyList' + i">
    <div class="title">
        {{ item.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        {{ item.content }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you can see, the items have an ID assigned that is simple a base string and their number. Let's say I want to trigger a scroll to `MyList31`. Once the list is loaded and rendered, how do I fetch the element with such ID and scroll to it?

I've searched around and found the ways you should *not* do it, and how to do it using ViewRefs, but these don't seem to work on dynamic elements, or do they? How would I do this?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36147846/1009922).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using property binding.

First, when I receive the parameter that defines which item to scroll into, I save it as a component property.

`this.toScrollInto = Object.keys(params)[0];`

Then, inside of the ngFor that builds it, I bind into it and make use of short-circuiting to call a function if there is a match.

```
<div class="items" *ngFor="let item of functionThatGetsItems(); let i = index" 
    #itemRef
    [class.scrolled]="i == this.toScrollInto && scrollIntoView(itemRef)">

    <div class="title">
        {{ item.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        {{ item.content }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

The function `scrollIntoView(Element)` then handles the scrolling using the provided Angular reference.

Comment: I don't think you want the "#" in front of the `itemRef` entry on the third line, that is, it should be `[class.scolled]="i == this.toScrollInto && scrollIntoView(itemRef)">`.

Answer (score 14):

You want the id to be on the actual item that the ng-for creates, not the ng-for itself. That would eliminate the need for any extra logic when passing data to the list from the component.

```js
// inside ngAfterViewInit() to make sure the list items render or inside ngAfterViewChecked() if you are anticipating live data using @Inputs
const itemToScrollTo = document.getElementById('item-' + id);
// null check to ensure that the element actually exists
if (itemToScrollTo) {
  itemToScrollTo.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

```html
<div class="list" *ngFor="let item of functionThatGetsItems(); let i = index">
  <div class="list-item" id="item-{{i}}">
    <div class="title">
        {{ item.title }}
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        {{ item.content }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `true` value is the default value for `scrollIntoView` [Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Parameters).

Answer (score 7):

This is not strictly angular, but you could do `document.querySelector('#MyList31').scrollIntoView()`.

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

For doing this strictly angular, this article may help you http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angular-js-scrolling-to-element-by-id.html

Comment: Depending on target browser support, you can also smooth scroll with this method.

Comment: Yes, that works indeed! But on other sources you can see this method is discouraged by Angular as it accesses native browser APIs.

Comment: @ChrisJaquez well, check the article i added, i am not so used to angular to give a concrete answer, sorry

Comment: That article is for AngularJS, I'm using Angular, which is a significantly different version. No worries, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template reference and call the native `scrollIntoView()` method. In your html:

```
<h2 #scrollToMe>Hi there</h2>
```

In your component:

```
@ViewChild('scrollToMe') scrollToMe: ElementRef;

...


this.scrollToMe.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
```

The `behavior: 'smooth'` animates the transition.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can use the following approach. First, modify the element that matches the specified ID to include a template reference variable for the target element. Simultaneously, create a duplicate of the element without a template reference variable for those elements that do not match the specified ID.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of functionThatGetsItems(); let i = index">
  <div #target *ngIf="i === id"></div>
  <div *ngIf="i !== id"></div>
</ng-container>
```

In your component, use `ViewChild` to get a reference to the target element and then call `scrollIntoView()` to scroll it into view.

```js
@ViewChild('target') target: ElementRef;
...
this.target.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(...);
```

---